Are there any Alternative Methods for Verifying App Links Without .well-known Directory on IIS?
I'm currently developing an Ionic React app with deep linking capabilities using Capacitor. I need to verify app links, but I'm facing an issue because our application is hosted on an ISS shared server, and we cannot create a .well-known directory. We neither can migrate to linux server because we use C# API and it must be hosted on windows machine. VPS is also not an option because of cost.
Typically, verifying app links involves placing a file in the .well-known directory to prove ownership of the domain. However, this is not possible in our hosting environment. I need an alternative method for app link verification.
Quetions

Are there any alternative methods for verifying app links that do not require the .well-known directory?
Can verification be done through DNS records or other server-side configurations that might be more flexible with ISS shared hosting that do not require any ssh or administrator premisions?
Are there any specific Capacitor or Ionic plugins or tools that could assist with this verification process under these constraints?

Additional Information

Framework: Ionic React
Capacitor Version: [Provide version]
Hosting Environment: ISS shared server "Plesk"

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Related Resources

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks

Thanks in advance for your help!

You MUST have .well-known directory, no other way around it!
